# EOL Windows Server 2003. Should I migrate to Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2012, migration, upgrade

In my environment I have 11 virtual W2k3 servers and I have to decide to migrate them to 2012 or not. None of them are AD server. Two of them are running SQL Server 2005, there are also some apps running on tomcat and jackrabbit repo. I'm considering pros and cons migrating to 2012, and maybe to newer SQL Server as well. Is security the only reason to perform this action? System is working good so far, so I need hard evidences for business to do this.

Comment: What bout "if your hardware fails - which it will - you will be in the dumps and can not rely on drivers being available for new hardware".

Comment: Those are VM machines.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/

Comment: I think you answered your own question in the title.  It says "EOL Windows server 2003"  It's EOL, no more patches coming your way shortly.  Why would you WANT to keep it in your environment?  Seems like that's reason enough.

Answer (score 2):

The hard evidence is lack of support coming in very soon. But migrating a complicated set of servers to a new platform is a tricky business - so the sooner you start it, the better. You might want to try it on one machine first, and build up on your experience. And since R2 has been out for some time, now is the time to do it.